# C# ZipArchive.CreateEntryFromFile() does not add file from disk to archive

Tags: .net-4.5, .net

I have following code in .NET 4.5 to send email attachment using SmtpClient.
I am adding memory stream created below to Attachement collection of message.

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Compression;

var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
{
    archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\Files\File1.txt", "File1.txt");
}
```

When I receive a email, it shows zip file but the archive does not have File1.txt. What's missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar scenario in a program, create Zip file in a MemoryStream. As Jack Bradford mentioned is important to perform the Close/Dispose operation, but there are some tricky issues left:

First you cannot Close/Dispose MemoryStrean, since you need it open to be able to send it by Email attachment.

Second, you cannot Close/Dispose the ZipArchive. Its underlying logic will perform a Close operation in the MemoryStream object.

Third, usually after writing a MemoryStream object, the pointer is left at the end of the stream. If you try to read from it you will read 0 bytes. This could be the reason why you are getting an empty zip file.

The solution is to set the  MemoryStream cursor at the beggining of the stream, so your next read operation will be able to get all the data:

```
  memoryStream.Position = 0;
  <Mail code>
  System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new    System.Net.Mime.ContentType(System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames.Application.Zip);
  System.Net.Mail.Attachment attachment = new System.Net.Mail.Attachment(memoryStream,"ZipFile.zip", ct.MediaType);
   <Add attachment to email and send email>
   <Stream and Zip Close/Dispose operations>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem what I did is:

```
 using (var archive = new ZipArchive(zipStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, false)) {
       archive.CreateEntryFromFile(udf.FilePath, Path.GetFileName(udf.FilePath));
 }
```

Used "false" in ZipArchive and on email part I did:

```
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(ai.Stream.ToArray()), ai.AttachedFilename, ai.MediaType));
```

I added a stream like `new MemoryStream(ai.Stream.ToArray())`and in email now the attachment is fine.

Answer (score -5):

Make sure you dispose the ZipArchive and close the MemoryStream

```
var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
    using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
    {
         archive.CreateEntryFromFile(@"c:\Files\File1.txt", "File1.txt");
    }

archive.Dispose();
memoryStream.Close();

//Send Email
```

Comment: The using statement handles disposing of the archive.  It would be better to recommend using two using statements, one for the memoryStream (missing) wrapped around the current using statement